# Insert into a junction table in MySQL when there is a foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to add `person_name` records FROM `person` to `person_job` table by giving these people a job value. person_job is my `junction` table. my job_id is the id of the job.

```
person table
```

person_id

person_name

**Desired result is below.**

person_id is a foreign key from `person` table, and I want to give the job id in the query manually, as I use phpMyAdmin, it will be easy.

```
person_job table (junction table from person and job tables.)
```

person_id

job_id

I've tried the query below, but I can't add ID values with it. Where should I put the id value?

```
INSERT INTO person_job(person_id)
          SELECT person_id
          FROM person
          WHERE person_id < 1500;
```

Comment: insert into person_job(person_id, job_id) values (1,1);

Comment: @SQL.injection, I want to aim person_id < 1500 rather than person_id = 1. Actually that what I was asking for.

Comment: No pictures please. Just proper DDLs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1: drop the foreign key and restore it after you populated the table and fixed the referential integrity.

Option 2 : assign an arbitrary job to these persons then  update them with their actual jobs manually. This arbitrary job could be a dummy one created just for this operation (`INSERT INTO  person_job(person_id, job_id) SELECT person_id, 999 ...`)

Option 3 : assign the value `NULL` as a job to these persons, if the definition of `job_id` allows.